# Elasticsearch Data in Grafana without timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am wondering if it is possible to have data from elasticsearch indices without timestamp attached to them.

I need a list of two columns as a drop down. This list is cross checked against another index to generate maps but if I zoom into the graph breaks cause the drop down list exists from time a to be but not from c to d. (lol)

My macgyver solution to this is to just add the list every few minutes into the index so on the graph, the data is reasonably dense. This allows the user to zoom in pretty well into different parts of the graph. But overtime this is going to make my index unreasonably large.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately... no.. One thing I guess u could do is have the data in SQL and use sql as the data source for dropdown Vars? looks like u dont need to define timestamp for it. You could end up with a static list on a dynamic elastic page. Unfortunately.. I have not worked with SQL..

Comment: Another possibility is to define your own query for elastic in the var definition. Point to a static timerange. Not sure if this will override the grafana time interval/break the query.. something to try out.